# show/hide fields based on selection in openerp 7

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have a **selection field** in openerp form

what I want is that when I select any value from this field , another field (which is hidden or invisible ) is shown automatically , based on the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it is possible to show or hide a field checking or unchecking a boolean field in your view (e.g. needs_moreinfo).

```
<field name="moreinfo" attrs="{'invisible':['needs_moreinfo','=', false]}" />
```

I guess you could do the same, based on the IDs of the elements of your selection field. But it has to be hardcoded and you have to know in advance the ids in you DB...